# Why is bootstrap:false the default in CakePHP's CakePlugin::load()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

When I say `CakePlugin::loadAll()` in CakePHP 2.6, it defaults to not run the plugins' bootstrap.

Why is it the default?
 
Why is it configurable at all? 
I mean what are the use cases of skipping the bootstrap of a plugin? 
Aren't plugins designed to work when their bootstrapping ran?

Comment: Probably 3/4 (75%) of all plugins listed [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp/tree/cake2) do neither have nor require their own bootstrap/routes. So no, they are not designed to have those by default.

Comment: Not having bootstraps does not need to have this configuration option. Not having them means in their case it is not ran. I just have never seen a plugin, where running it's bootstrap is optional, and can work both ways, so I was curious. I'll look at the list, thanks!

Comment: At least one of my plugins bootstrap is optional. The reason is to make it work out of the box but the user clearly will have to modify it's content if he want's to adept it to his needs at some point.

Answer (score 2):

- Loading everything by default is bad practice IMHO (overhead by default, might screw things up as well without the user being aware of what is causing it)
- Giving the user a choice is good
- You might want to load the plugin at a later point or conditionally (DebugKit)
- You might want to alter the bootstrap of the plugin completely by copying its content to the apps bootstrap.php and modifying it there

The question is pretty... strange. Usually people complain only about things they *can't* do. Having a choice is great. And I dont know what the problem with this is. It will make it load everything by default:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll([['bootstrap' => true]]);
```

[It's in the documentation.](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakePlugin.html#_loadAll)

Comment: I didn't complain, I was curious. If I would present this question as a complaint, I would complain about the default value, but that's really not a big thing. Checking if a plugin has a bootstrap, and checking if a config value is true is the same overhead IMHO, but I didn't dig in `CakePlugin` to see how it does its things. The last point makes sense to me, but the others didn't convinced me. OOP itself controls how much choice the user have, so having something designed to be used in a specific way is also not a bad thing. But these parts of programming really are matter of taste.

Comment: Neither bootstrap nor routes represent an inheritable class. And I don't think OOP has anything to do with basic configuration and bootstrapping except you wrote a complete OOP based bootstrapping system which doesn't make much sense IMHO because it's overkill. Symfony for example uses tons of YML files. First point in the list is the most important one: I don't want to add something and it magically starts doing things without my explicit permission or interaction.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_design